# Hibernate OneToMany with an interface

Tags: java, hibernate, interface

At the moment I have the problem where I need an `OneToMany ArrayList` of different objects with the same interface.

For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
public class Store {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store")
    private List<Product> allProducts;
}

public interface Product {
    String getProductCode();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car implements Product{
    int wheels;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "computer")
public class Computer implements Product{
    String cpu;
}
```

I just want it to be easy to add other products by just implementing the `Product` interface. But hibernate gives me this error: `'One To Many' attribute value type should not be 'Product'`.

I found some posts about this issue but they are pretty old (5 years or older). They all ended up with that this wasn't possible back then.

Did hibernate add any functionality in the last 5 years to solve this problem or are there any other good ways of adding multiple objects in the same `OneToMany` relation? I don't want to update my Store class everytime I add a new product.

Comment: What if you use a mapped superclass instead of the interface ? Can you ?

Comment: @gtosto Yeah I think I can. But I'm trying to do it the cleanest way. And a interface is better in my situation.

Comment: You cannot use mapped SuperClass here, compiler throw the error: 'One To Many' attribute value type should not be 'Mapped Superclass'

Answer (score 1):

> Did hibernate add any functionality in the last 5 years to solve this
>   problem or are there any other good ways of adding multiple objects in
>   the same OneToMany relation? I don't want to update my Store class
>   every time I add a new product.

I think that the best way to match your needs is to *promote* `Product` to an Entity (or at least to make it a mapped SuperClass). Anyway, the [@Any](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-any) annotation could help in your situation, which is used to model polymorphic associations.